create topics and subscription for gcp pubsub emulator from cli
This documentation(https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) tells me that project id/ host / data directory could be associated to an emulator from the cli using the command (gcloud beta emulators pubsub start). Is there any possibility where I could use the cli to create the topic or subscription in the future?
Below is the docker compose file.
version: "3"
  services:
      pubsub:
        container_name: pubsub
        image: google/cloud-sdk
        ports:
          - '8085:8085'
        command: ["gcloud", "beta", "emulators", "pubsub", "start", "--host-port", "0.0.0.0:8085", "--project=test-project"]

  pubsub-create-sub:
    depends_on:
      pubsub:
        condition: service_started
    image: google/cloud-sdk
    command: ["/bin/sh", "/init/init.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./init.sh:/init/init.sh:ro

This is how the init script looks like
#!/bin/sh
export PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=pubsub:8085
export PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=test-project
gcloud pubsub topics create test-topic

This does not create the topic for the emulator.

Yes, you are correct. Given that you have correctly installed the gcloud CLI (For local shells)
Create topic:
gcloud pubsub topics create TOPIC_ID

Pull:
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create SUBSCRIPTION_ID --topic=TOPIC_ID

Push:
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create SUBSCRIPTION_ID \
    --topic=TOPIC_ID \
    --push-endpoint=PUSH_ENDPOINT

All these commands can be found here. Which I also recommend to review as is this is a good resource for these topics.

I don't think this answers my question, I have edited my question for better understanding ( I was talking about the emulator), just to rephrase I was looking if gcp further wants to enhance the cli to allow creation of topics and subscription.

@Satarupa Have you found anything? Looking for this too right now.

It seems it's not possible directly from gcloud command, at least I haven't been able to do so.
What I found to work and is the easiest is to use curl and the PubSub REST API to create the topic/subscription.
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/acme/topics/topic-name
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -X PUT -d '{"topic": "projects/acme/topics/topic-name"}' "http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/acme/subscriptions/sub-name"

The acme project can be anything, just need to be constant.
